# Asp.net Core Migration, Post actions no longer work

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have ported an Asp.Net project to .Net Core and have noticed my POST endpoint no longer works.

```
    [HttpGet, Route("Concert/Add/{eventId:int?}")]
            public ActionResult Add(int eventId)
            {
//This works
    }

     [HttpPost]
            [Route("Concert/Add")]
            public IActionResult Add(EntryViewModel entryViewModel)
            {
//This action is never reached. I get a 404 Not found in browser
    }
```

In my view I have the following form:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Concert", new { eventId = Model.EventId }, FormMethod.Post, null, new { @class = "center-block entryform AddEntry" }))
    {
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Forename, new { @class = "control-label entryLabel" })
            <div class="">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Forename, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

My StartUp.cs Configure() looks like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Events",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{eventId?}");
            });
```

If I change my Post endpoint route to be [Route("Customer/Add/{entryViewModel})"] then it navigates to that action, but the model is null. Am I missing another configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo on your route, the endpoint will not be hit.

```
[Route("Convert/Add/{entryViewModel}")]
```

It should be

```
[Route("Concert/Add/{entryViewModel}")]
```

I would also remove the `new { eventId = Model.EventId }` in the `@Html.BeginForm` to ensure the `EntryViewModel` is serialised and passed up to the HTTP endpoint correctly.

Additional, since you have not provided your `EntryViewModel` class, I would ensure that it has the correct getter and setters associated in order for the model binding to work, for example:

```
public class EntryViewModel
{
   [Required]
   [DisplayName(Name="Forename")]
   public string Forename { get; set; }
}
```

And in your form you could use the [ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
<form asp-controller="Concert" asp-action="Add" method="post">
    Forename:  <input asp-for="Forename" /> 
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: My bad, that's a copy and paste error into Stack. I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FromBody] for parameter

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("Concert/Add")]
 public IActionResult Add([FromForm]EntryViewModel entryViewModel)
 {

 }
```

And also I see:

```
new { eventId = Model.EventId }
```

So, it is better

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("Concert/Add/{eventId:int}")]
 public IActionResult Add(int eventId,[FromForm]EntryViewModel entryViewModel)
 {

 }
```

Comment: It still doesn't like that :(. Is it the attribute routing? Does it need to be "turned on"?

Comment: can you get http request from inspector to see how formed your request url and data?

Comment: Or one more feature. Remove new { eventId = Model.EventId } from Http.BeginForm. Then [Route("Concert/Add")] and public IActionResult Add([FromBody]EntryViewModel entryViewModel)

Comment: This got me closer. Looks like I need to use [FromForm] rather than [FromBody]

Comment: Yep. I use angular and use [FromBody]. My mistake. Update answer.